# Incorrect sum in for loop Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, for-loop, sum, qstringlistmodel

Following c++ code in qt is used by me to add values to an integer(initial value 10) and store it in a QStringList. But when I print the values of the StringList on to 3 labels it prints 10 on all lables though it should be 20,30 and 40 since I increment a by 10 through the for loop!

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QStringList array;
    int a =10;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        a=+10;
        array<<QString::number(a);
    }
    ui->label->setText(array[0]);
    ui->label_2->setText(array[1]);
    ui->label_2->setText(array[2]);
}
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: Your assignment is `a = +10`, not `a += 10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
a =+ 10;
// equivalent to
a = +10;
```

That means you are assigning 10 to `a`.

You need to use the form below to increment it by 10:

```
a += 10;
```

Comment: Thanx but why doesn't =+  return any error?

Comment: @SamanKarunaratne You can write  `a = +10` or `a = -10` like in math .

Comment: Because you are assigning a positive 10 to a and it's totally acceptable, there isn't any programming error..